# Docker ignores local project

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a local project folder with apache, seems to default to the server message of "It works" instead of running my project folder.  When I go to 127.0.0.1:8080

```
  sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v "$PWD:/home/me/public_html/project-folder" httpd
```

I'm using ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 1):

you need to mount the location of your project to this directory in the container: `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`

try this:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v "/home/me/public_html/project-folder:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs" httpd
```

this is explained here: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/

Comment: thanks, I tried and I get the default apache2 welcome page, not the content of the project folder.  Maybe I'm missing something, is other configuration needed.  Normally I can run a project in the command line in my project folder with 'php -S localhost:3000' and it works.

Comment: Hi GRAV, what is the full path on the filesystem for your project? It should be replaced with /home/me/public_html/project-folder in the above command

Comment: that is the full path to the project folder

Comment: I actually changed '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs'  to '/var/www/html' it gives me the page now, but the routing for other pages is broken